# Juju Charm branding guidelines

Tags: juju

Are there any branding guidelines available related to the trademarks "Juju" and "Charm"?

I'm looking for details on how the terms "Juju" and "Charm" can or cannot be used in documentation.

Can I say something like "*product X has been charmed*" or "*charming of the product X is underway*".

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.** I am not trained in this field, so I have no idea if I interpret this the correct way. You can always contact Canonical using the [trademark enquiry form](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us)*

The Juju trademark is managed the same as the Ubuntu trademark. You can use it in your documentation and other parts of your software to show compatibility. You cannot use it in software titles.

It is also very important to make it clear that Canonical does not endorse you. This means that you cannot say "Canonical approves this message" or "Official Juju Charm IDE"

[Ubuntu's Intellectual Property Policies](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)

> You will require Canonical’s permission to use:
>
> - (i) any mark ending with the letters UBUNTU or BUNTU which is sufficiently similar to the Trademarks or any other confusingly similar mark, and
> - (ii) any Trademark in a domain name or URL or for merchandising purposes.
>
> **You cannot use the Trademarks in software titles.** If you are producing software for use with or on Ubuntu **you may reference Ubuntu, but must avoid:**
>
> - (i) **any implication of endorsement**, or
> - (ii) **any attempt to unfairly or confusingly capitalise on the goodwill of Canonical or Ubuntu.** You can use the Trademarks in discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, provided that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.
>
> You can write articles, create websites, blogs or talk about Ubuntu, provided that it is clear that you are in no way speaking for or on behalf of Canonical and that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical. Canonical reserves the right to review all use of Canonical’s Trademarks and to object to any use that appears outside of this IPRights Policy.

Comment: This seems right, +1.